# Enable DataGrid sorting for first column in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, mvvm, datagrid

I have a DataGrid in WPF with autogenerated columns.

How can I disable sorting functionality of all the rows except the first one which corresponds time in my Source.

I am following MVVM pattern and I know that CanUserSortColumns is disabling sorting for all the columns. I want to disable all but the first column.

Should I write trigger or interaction or something else? All the help is appreciated.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataTable}" 
        CanUserSortColumns="False">
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this code [snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296532/making-a-datagrid-column-header-sortable-in-wpf-using-c-sharp) for you:

```
<my:DataGridTemplateColumn  SortMemberPath="CompleteDate" Header="Complete Date" CanUserSort="true">
            <my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock.Text>
                                <Binding Path="CompleteDate" ConverterCulture="en-GB" StringFormat="{}{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"/>
                            </TextBlock.Text>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </my:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Use the CanUserSort Property to define it's sortable-state column explicit. The SortMemberPath defines the Property you use for sorting. Hope this helps.

**UPDATE:**
If you are using autogenerated columns you can't access them via xaml. So you need to access them in code File.

I'm not familiar with the xaml Grid but would expect something like:

```
//Bound Data here so that the Grid generate the columns

int i = 0;
foreach (DataColumn column in myGrid.ColumnCollection)
{
   if (i == 0)
      column.CanSortUser = true;
   else
      column.CanSortUser = false;

   i++;
}
```

The original Typenames can differ but something this way should be possible.

**UPDATE-2**

If you don't want to hurt the MVVM you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236222/how-can-i-access-a-control-in-mvvm-model-in-viewmodel). There is described how to use Interfaces to access the code and stay independet with your view and viewmodel.

Comment: Well, it does not work for me because i am auto generating the columns so it is giving exception such in that way: ''Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.''

Comment: @stackerflow i think in this case it's not possible via xaml. But xaml is doing nothing else as using Properties. So if you autogenerate your columns, you should be able to access this columns in code file. Iam not familiar with xaml grid but try something like: myGrid.ColumnCollection[0].CanUserSort = true for every other column you set the value to false. For sure you need to generate the columns before using this approach.

Comment: Yes, as you said it can be handled in code but i am using MVVM pattern and actually i do not want to get coupling between viewModel and the view. If there is any possible workaround, it will be really usefull.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that `DataGridColumnHeader` has the `CanUserSort` property as a local computed property. It can been set by manually generating the columns (what you don't want).

If it was a property with setter you could create a `DataTrigger` looking at `TabIndex` == 0 and set through `Setter` in xaml Style.

Your only chance by using `AutoGeneratedColumns` is the following:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataTable}" 
    CanUserSortColumns="True"
    AutoGeneratedColumns="DataGrid_OnAutoGeneratedColumns">
</DataGrid>
```

your codebehind:

```
private void DataGrid_OnAutoGeneratedColumns(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid dg = sender as DataGrid;
    if (dg == null) return;
    dg.Columns.ToList().Select((col, indx) => new {Col = col, Indx = indx}).ToList().ForEach(obj => obj.Col.CanUserSort = obj.Indx == 0);
}
```

This enables the first columns `UserCanSort` property and disables the others. This function is independend from your **viewmodel** and can been placed at your `view.xaml.cs` code behind file.

**EDIT:**

If you won't have any codebehind you can just do it by using your own `DataGridControl`.

MyDataGrid.cs

```
namespace YourNamespace {
    public class MyDataGrid : DataGrid
    {
        protected override void OnAutoGeneratedColumns(EventArgs e)
        {
            DataGrid dg = sender as DataGrid;
            if (dg == null) return;
            dg.Columns.ToList().Select((col, indx) => new {Col = col, Indx = indx}).ToList().ForEach(obj => obj.Col.CanUserSort = obj.Indx == 0);

            base.OnAutoGeneratedColumns(e);
        }
    }
}
```

your view:

```
<YourNamespace:MyDataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataTable}" 
    CanUserSortColumns="True">
</YourNamespace:MyDataGrid>
```

and you are done without a single line codebehind.

Comment: The main point is i do not want write any code into code behind. I am following strict MVVM pattern which not allows to write any code-behind.

Comment: I can comprehend this. But the solution in this answer is an extension to your `DataGrid` controls behaviour and is fully independend from any data and business logic. So the 3 lines aren't against MVVM pattern. They belong to the view that consists of xaml and xaml.cs (code behind). I agree with not putting these lines to your viewmodel!

Comment: Well it can be useful also. I am going to give it a shot. Thanks.